# How to split this duplicated Azure DevOps steps into a reusable template

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have the following Azure DevOps template, which is currently hardcoded to some specific files. I'm hoping to refactor it into a simpler template using loops so I don't need to duplicate (and hardcode) specific files.

[ pseduo code for brevity ]

```
#tests.yml

steps:

  # pre-test steps. This is done once.

  - script: install tool1
  - script: install tool2
  - script: setup path stuff.

  # Tests
  - script: test project1 |
            display codecoverage to console-out
  - script: test project 2 |
            display codecoverage to console-out

  # Post-tests
  - script: upload coverage report for project1
  - script: upload coverage report for project2
  - task: PublishTestResults@2 # publish test results to Azure DevOps.
```

So notice how i'm doing this *per project*

- test project
- display codecoverage result to console-out (so i can see the results here)
- upload result to 3rd party website (for others to see also)

I was hoping there might be a way I can someone pass in the info into the template and then just loop through the array of input data.

like this..

```
steps:

  # pre tests.
  ...

  # tests
  foreach project in projects
    - script: test project |
              display code coverage report
    - script: upload report

  # post-test
  ...
```

can this be done in Azure DevOps ?

  -

Answer (score 5):

Personally, maybe the keywords [`each`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#extend-from-a-template) is what you are looking for?

For sample:

**azure-pipelines.yml**

```
extends:
  template: template.yml
  parameters:
    buildArgs:  
      Arg1 : $(arg1-value)
      Arg2 : $(arg2-value)
```

**template.yml**

```
parameters:
- name: buildArgs 
  type: object
  default: [] 
stages:
  - stage: EachLoop
    displayName: Run Each extends
    jobs:
    - job: looping
      steps:
      - ${{ each arg in parameters.buildArgs }}:
        - bash: |
            echo ${{ arg.key }}
            echo ${{ arg.value }}
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildOther]${{ arg.value }}"
          displayName: ${{ arg.key }}
        - bash: |
            echo "buildstring=$(buildOther)"
          displayName: ECHO-${{ arg.key }}
```

[image]

---

For your scenario, just need put `run test`/ `display` / `upload` steps in template.yml. Use `each` along with `parameters` to extend the template, so that you can achieve looping.

Comment: Thanks Merlin for the awesome answer! Really appreciate it. Unfortunately, I've been unable to get it working. I wish to pass in ONE parameter with one value. Not key/value. eg. `buildArgs` : project1, project2, project3`. I've not been able to get that bit, working.

Comment: @Pure.Krome Is it okay to give me a sample data? The parameter data structure you want? If okay, just update it into your question:-)

Comment: I have already done this in the opening post? (i haven't edited it..). See the 2nd code block example. It needs to pass in a sequence of project names (strings) ... and then I `foreach` over each project and run by 2x steps, there (which could _also_ be a template!)

Comment: @Pure.Krome, You just provide the sample about the steps. But the most important content is configure correct parameters to make the extends work with `each`. So, what I want is you could share me a sample parameters structure. Then I can do help on make that work with `each` for you.