# How to pass a list of string parameters to an Azure DevOps template

Tags: azure, azure-devops

In a [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61081717/how-to-split-this-duplicated-azure-devops-steps-into-a-reusable-template), I was trying to get create an Azure DevOps template.

Now that I know how to do that, I'm trying to pass in a list of strings to the template and use them in the template, like so:

**azure_pipelines.yml**

```
extends:
  template: AzurePipelines/job.yml
  parameters:
    projects:
      - FirstProject.csproj
      - SecondProject.csproj
```

and in this template...

**job.yml**

```
steps:
 (for each projectFileName in projects)
 - bash echo $(projectFileName)
 - run code in the build.yml template using $(projectFileName)
 - run code in the test.yml template using $(projectFileName)
 - run code in the publish.yml template using $(projectFileName)
```

So for each project name handed into the template, run the template steps.

I'm not sure how to pass in an array of strings and how to test that it works?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT I have .. but i was still hoping to get another answer which was a bit more closer to the question.

Comment: It seems you are looking for each function, check my reply below.

Answer (score 6):

It seems you are looking for [each function](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/pull/2#issuecomment-452748467):

```yaml
# my-template.yml
parameters:
- name: 'projects'
  type: object
  default: []
steps:
- ${{ each project in parameters.projects }}:
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: 'Publish ${{ project }}'
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/${{ project }}.zip'
```

```yaml
# ci.yml
steps:
- template: my-template.yml
  parameters:
    projects:
    - test1
    - test2
```

Comment: so just to confirm with the `my-template.yml` file, you define a section `parameters:` but don't actually put anything in there? That's not a bug or typo?

Comment: Please check my update. Also, you could refer to the following documentation for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#iterative-insertion

Comment: This gives me "Unexpected value: 'projectList'" error.

Comment: There is no parameter type `projectList` according to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops

Comment: The `type` should be `object` not `projectsList`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I found to accomplish the use of templates is by using the templates from within the main yaml file pipeline. This way you will have access to all the variables and variable groups defined in the main template. Using this architecture you will be able to bundle several steps into a template then run it from the main yaml file. Eg:

**azure_pipelines.yml**

```
variables:
- name: projectFileName
  value: "Variable 1 value"
- name: VAR2
  value: "Variable 2 value"

trigger:
  - master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- template: templates/job.yml
- template: templates/test.yml
```

**templates/job.yml**

```
steps:
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Run Bash Command'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      print "Variable value: " $(projectFileName)
```

Hope it helps